# Bootstrap data-loading-text ONLY if client-side validation passes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with a couple data fields. Each one has a quick client-side validation check. There is then a submit button:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ImportApi", "EveApi", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "register-form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.KeyId)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.KeyId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.KeyId)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.vCode)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.vCode)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.vCode)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" id="register-btn" value="Register" data-loading-text="Loading..." />
}
```

I currently have:

```
$('#register-form').submit(function () {
    $('#register-btn').button('loading');
    return true;
});
```

Which changes the button to loading text when the form is submitted. However, it does this even if the client-side validation fails, causing it to remain in its "loading" state indefinitely because the page isn't reloaded.

I'm looking for a way to have it only call the `$('#register-btn').button('loading');` when the form is actually submitted to the server and the page is guaranteed to be refreshed.

Comment: Where is the validation?

Comment: My understanding is that MVC adds it automatically using the @Html.TextBoxFor() because the model is strongly typed and the model class uses data annotations to specify the rules. At least according to "http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model" which says "The errors are enforced both client-side (using JavaScript and jQuery) and server-side (in case a user has JavaScript disabled)." If you examine the source html it shows that the input field has data-val="true" data-val-number="..." data-val-required="..."

Comment: Interesting, I don't think that was a feature of MVC3, that's why I was confused (maybe I'm wrong). Well there has to be something you can check to see if all fields are valid. I'll see what I can find

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about calling the `valid()` method before setting the text?

Something like:

```
$('#register-form').submit(function () {
   if($(this).valid()) {
     $('#register-btn').button('loading');
     return true;
   }
});
```

Comment: That is perfect, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the form is validated using `valid()`. If the form is valid you can change the text.

```
var form = $('#formId');
form.validate();

form.find('[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( form.valid() ) {
        form.find('[type="submit"]').button('loading');
    }
});
```